# List all files and folders in order using PHP

Tags: php

My code:

```
<?php

$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
$files = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_file');
$all = $dirs + $files;

foreach ($all as $value){
    echo '<li><a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></li>'; 
}
?>
```

This returns all files and folders but in random order:

```
Array
(
    [2] => New folder
    [6] => dir
    [7] => dir1
    [8] => dir2
    [9] => dir3
    [0] => A_test.txt
    [1] => Index.php
    [3] => app.exe
    [4] => b_test
    [5] => delete.php
    [10] => hello.png
    [11] => z_test.txt
)
```

`sort()` doesn't work. I want to sort them like default order.

Comment: So? What "order" are you trying to do? Do you want to sort? If so, there are many array functions for sorting, such as `sort()`

Comment: why can't you just use `$all = glob('*');` or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Just like Half Crazed mentioned, you are just missing the sort() of the files before echoing them.

```
<?php

$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
$files = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_file');
$all = $dirs + $files;

sort($all); //sort them

foreach ($all as $value){
    echo '<li><a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></li>'; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

They aren't really in random order. The default behavior of [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) is to sort the names it returns. You actually have to use `GLOB_NOSORT` flag to override this if you *don't* want them sorted. They look random because the sort is case sensitive, and uppercase names appear at the top. If you want to sort them case-insensitively, use [`natcasesort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) on your two arrays before you combine them.

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
natcasesort($dirs);
$files = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_file');
natcasesort($files);
$all = $dirs + $files;

foreach ($all as $value){
    echo '<li><a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a></li>';
}
```